# FastAPI + Strawberry GraphQL Filter Conditions

Tags: python-3.x, strawberry-graphql

I am currently build microservice using FastAPI + Strawberry GraphQL. I want to expose filters for the models with and/or condition. For example,

```
{
   Student(where:{and[{AgeGt: 15},{PercentageLt: 75}]}) {
     edges {
       node {
          Name
          Age
          Percentage
     }
   }
}
```

Is this possible? Any reference or example would greatly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Strawberry you can use [input types](https://strawberry.rocks/docs/types/input-types) to define arguments for your queries

Here's an example what should help you with definining filters using strawberry:

```py
from typing import Optional, List, TypeVar, Generic
from datetime import date

import strawberry

T = TypeVar("T")

@strawberry.input
class AbelFilter(Generic[T]):
    eq: Optional[T] = None
    gt: Optional[T] = None
    lt: Optional[T] = None



@strawberry.input
class WhereFilter:
    foo: Optional[AbelFilter[str]] = None
    bar: Optional[AbelFilter[int]] = None
    baz: Optional[AbelFilter[str]] = None


@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def student(self, where: WhereFilter) -> str:
        return str(where)

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)
```

See this on the [Strawberry Playground](https://la4de.github.io/strawberry-playground/#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)

Comment: How would I add "and"/"or" condition in above model?